# Easy way of Multiple XML file search

Tags: c#, xml

I want to search for an element value in all the XML files(assume 200+) in a folder using C#.

My scenario is each file will contain multiple item tags.So i have to check all  item tags for User Selected SearchValue. Eg: ABC123

Currently i am using foreach loop and it's taking longtime.

Could you please suggest me a better option to get result much faster

Following is my current code implementation.

```
string[] arrFiles = Directory.GetFiles(temFolder, "*.xml");
            foreach (string file in arrFiles)
            {
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(file);
                XmlNodeList lstEquip = doc.SelectNodes("scene/PackedUnit/Items/ItemCode");
                foreach (XmlNode xnEquip in lstEquip)
                {
                    if (xnEquip.InnerText.ToUpper() == equipCode.ToUpper())
                    {
                        String[] strings = file.Split('\\');
                        string fileName = strings[strings.Count() - 1];
                        fileName = fileName.Replace(".xml", "");
                        lstSubContainers.Add(fileName);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Send a snippet of the XML and I should be able to point you to one or two solutions. Also what is an "item tag"?

Comment: File Size between 100 Kb to 1 MB

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first thing to work out is *why* it's taking a long time. You haven't provided any code, so it's hard to say what's going on.

One option is to parallelize the operation, using a pool of tasks each working on a single document at a time. In an ideal world you'd probably read from the files on a single thread (to prevent thrashing) and supply the files to the pool as you read them - but just reading in multiple threads it probably a good starting point. Using .NET 4's Parallel Extensions libraries would make this reasonably straightforward.

Personally I like the LINQ to XML API for querying, rather than using the "old" `XmlElement` etc API, but it's up to you. I wouldn't expect it to make much difference. Using `XmlReader` instead *could* be faster, avoiding creating as much garbage - but I would try to find out where the time is going in the "simple" code first. (I personally find `XmlReader` rather harder to use correctly than the "whole document in memory" APIs.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing forward-only reading and not manipulating the Xml in anyway, switching to an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) should speed up the processing, although I can't imagine it will really make a massive difference (maybe a second or two atmost) with the file sizes you have.

I've recently had to parse a 250mb XML file using LINQ-to-XML in Silverlight (a test app) and that took seconds to do. What is your machine?